# For the following complex sequence, how does this fact below follow?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We have a sequence $(t_n |y_n|^{q/p})$ such that $(y_n) \in \ell_q$ and $t_1, t_2, t_3, \dots $ are suitable complex numbers with modulus 1, and $1/q + 1/p=1$.

Then how does it follow that $t_n y_n=|y_n|$?

Comment: The keyword here is "suitable". This is only true for a very specific choice of the $t_n$. (You need that $\arg t_n = -\arg y_n$ for all $n$ for which $y_n \ne 0$.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer Can you please answer in a little more detail? My complex analysis requires some brushing up and this isn't my homework. I'm trying to understand a proof of the reflexivity of the space $\ell_p$.

Comment: You don't need complex analysis for this, just basic complex numbers. (Look up polar representation of complex numbers...)